# How to get the files from the hierarchy of Zip Folder

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have a directory Structure like this:
 A.zip -
  A -
  a -
  1.dat
  2.dat

I want to read the files 1.dat and 2.dat inside the directory hierarchy. I am able to read the file contentby C#, if the file is directly inside the zip folder but due to the inner directory structure is become inaccessible.

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to make your question a bit clearer and add some more information, e.g. some code of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are reading your zip file contents without an example, however reading zip file contents using the `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assemblies is pretty simplistic. See the following example of how to read all files regardless of subdirectory within a zip file:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ZipReader
{
    class Program
    {
        const string zipPath = @"D:\test\test.zip";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entry.FullName);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
folder1/test1.txt
folder2/test2.txt
```

To get the contents you can simply call `entry.Open()` on each file which returns a `Stream` you can handle however you need to.